# Best way to access double arrays

Tags: arrays

I am having some trouble using a double array. The following piece of code will not compile, but I believe it should show my issue:

```
static uns8 level6[2][8]  {              
  = {0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0}};

int i, j;     /* Loop Index */
int level[8];                    

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        if (TRUE) {
            level[][] = level6[][];   
        }
        else {
             level[i][] = level6[i][]; 
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is if a variable is true then I want to use the second part of the double array `{0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0}` and otherwise use the first one `{0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0}`.

Now I'm stuck on how to actually write up that code. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
 for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
if (TRUE) {
    level[][] = level6[][];   
}
else {
     level[i][] = level6[i][]; 
}
```

you should have

```
for (j = 0; j < 8; j++){
   if (TRUE) {
      level[j] = level6[1][j];   
   }
   else {
      level[j] = level6[0][j]; 
   }
}
```

because you only want to copy one of the lists into level, so you only need to loop through the length of that list, putting the number based on the boolean.